# Validation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, validation

Alright so what I want to do is validate some fields in a form if a checkbox is selected. I am doing a registration form where they can pay by check later or by credit card there and then.

They will select their payment method via checkbox, what I want to do is if they choose to pay via credit card then those fields need to be validated, however if they choose to pay by check then those fields won't need to be validated. Is there a way to do this using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes,

- you can toggle a class on the fields to be validated on the change of the checkbox.
- configure your validator to validate only the elements that have this class applied.

It would be nice from a UI perspective to hde form-elements that are not needed to fill-in. EG: creditcard-number can be hidden when the user selects to pay by Check.
In that case you only have to validate te fields that are `:visible`

roughly like:

```
$('#checkboxPaymentType').bind('change', function () {
       $('ccNumber').hide();
       $('checkValue').show();
});

$("#paymentForm").validate({ignore:':hidden'});
```

Answer (score 0):

A little edit from the script from Caspar Kleijne:

```
$(function(){
  $('#checkboxPaymentType').bind('change', function () {
     if ( $(this).attr("checked") ){
       $('#ccNumber').hide();
       $('#checkValue').show();
     }
     else{
       $('#ccNumber').show();
       $('#checkValue').hide();
     }
  });
  $('form').submit(function(e){
    var form_ok = true;
    $(this).find("input,select,textarea").filter(":visible").each(function(){
      if ( $(this).val() == '' ){
        form_ok = false;
        return false;
      }
    });
    if ( !form_ok ){
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('blabla');
      return false;
    }
    else
      return true;
    }
  });
});
```